# jq --stream help needed to parse json

Tags: json, jq

I have a very large JSON text which I need to parse using

```
jq --stream
```

However, there exists no elaborate use cases or blogs to understand this.

JSON structure is as follows:

```
{
  "userActivities": {
    "-----P9E3PJB5bTO1xrO": {
      "aaid": "84dae6bd-cb3a-409c-9940-844f035b5fc7",
      "callsign": "2day",
      "deviceId": "1b771f137d1bc6ea",
      "dow": "Thursday",
      "downloadFlag": "N",
      "email": "ckcafeandcatering@gmail.com",
      "emailSha256": "6ab0992297a9478be9ae7ff26d811b1116c45a0c819ff1c9628c9b7ca4ec4129",
      "event": "streamStop",
      "firebaseUID": "anvlMojJFvQEvMXQW6GeRzLKCIA2",
      "halfHourFull": "10h1",
      "liveFlag": "Y",
      "localDate": "1970-01-01",
      "localHalfHour": 1,
      "login": "google",
      "minutesSinceMidnight": 601,
      "quarterHourFull": "10q1",
      "stationName": "2DayFM104.1"
    },
    "-GuGCJDEprMKczAMDUj8": {
      "deviceId": "399a649c6cee6209",
      "dow": "Thursday",
      "downloadFlag": "N",
      "event": "streamStart",
      "halfHourFull": "18h1",
      "liveFlag": "Y",
      "localDate": "2009-01-01",
      "localHalfHour": 1,
      "minutesSinceMidnight": 1080,
      "quarterHourFull": "18q1",
      "stationName": "hit 105",
      "streamListenMethod": "Headphones",
      "timestampLocal": "2009-01-01T18:00:33.679+10:00",
      "timestampUTC": "2009-01-01T08:00:33.679Z"
    }
  }
}
```

I want to put a filter on localDate i.e. select only those arrays where localDate = '2009-01-01'.

Currently, I'm feeding my JSON to the below command and it gives all the arrays.

```
jq -cn --stream 'fromstream(1|truncate_stream(inputs | select(.[0][] == "userActivities") | del(.[0][0])))'
```

How do I put a filter? Kindly suggest. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please follow the [mcve] guidelines. Also, it would be helpful if you modified the wording of the question using standard JSON terminology for arrays and objects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Working with the output of your existing template:

- Append this filter:

  ```
    select(.localDate == "2009-01-01")
  ```
- So your modified command becomes:

  ```
  jq -cn --stream 'fromstream(1|truncate_stream(inputs | select(.[0][] == "userActivities") | del(.[0][0]))) | select(.localDate == "2009-01-01")'
  ```

Comment: Thanks for the input. Can you exactly explain how does the path and leaves value work. I cannot find any good documentation to this. For example: how did .[0][0] corresponds to "userActivities"?

Comment: Ok. I thought your filters were intentional. The reason `.[0][0]` is `userActivities` is because `userActivities` is the second top level of the JSON object, and once you stream your input, `[0`] represents everything between the outer `{}`'s, and `[0][0]` represents everything in the first index. In this case you only have `userActivities` so therefore the stream will have `[[0,0],"userActivities"]`.  The filter is removing the arbitrary (i.e. `"-----P9E3PJB5bTO1xrO"`) values from the `userActivities` objects, and then returning only the matching objects as top level objects filtered by date.

Comment: Many thanks for the explanation. Really appreciated. So, if I understood it correctly then in the below mentioned JSON the key users should be [0][1]. Am I correct?{
  "userActivities": {
    "-----P9E3PJB5bTO1xrO": {
      "aaid": "84dae6bd-cb3a-409c-9940-844f035b5fc7"
    }
 },
 "users":{
 "-----xyz": {
      "email": "abc@gmail.com"    
   },
 "-----abc": {
      "email": "xyz@gmail.com"
    }
 }
 }